# Assigning an ID to a new object

Tags: nhibernate, oop, repository

I've got a simple domain object, `Movie`, with the following constructor:

```
public Movie(string title, int year = 0, Genre genre = Genre.None, int length = 0, IEnumerable<string> actors = null) { ... }
```

There is no ID parameter, as there couldn't be a way to know up front what the ID would be. `Movie` does have an `int Id` property.

This object would be sent to my `MovieRepository`, which uses NHibernate. The repository has a method for adding movies: `void AddMovie(Movie movie) { ... }`.

Suppose I want to interact with the object after it is inserted, perhaps to display the data or change properties. I would need the object with the `Id` property set, or would need to know the ID generated by the database.

Should I change my `AddMovie` method to return the same movie with the ID set, or should I return the resulting ID value? Or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `Session.Save()` or `Session.SaveOrUpdate()` is called, the `id`  will be returned to you for future queries.

See Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411127/is-it-true-that-nhibernate-isession-savenewtransiententity-will-only-return-gen).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm able to receive the ID, then get and return the newly saved object.

Comment: @Grant: I'd also recommend you get this book.. it helped me alot: http://www.amazon.com/NHibernate-Beginners-Guide-Aaron-Cure/dp/1847198902

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend change `AddMovie` to return the newly created `Movie` with its Id assigned.

Since the `Session.SaveOrUpdate()` method already returns the object with its Id, that is quite straightforward.